# Raster clipping over 1300 km2 orthophotos

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, clip, orthophoto

I have all of Denmark in 25 cm orthophotos added to my ArcMap (mosaic dataset). I've added a polygon of an area covering over 1300 km2. I've used the raster clip tool to clip the data into a new raster dataset. All data is on a network drive. This process has taken over 32 hours so far.

Is there a difference in speed and such by doing raster clip or is it better to maybe use export data?

Or what is faster? Without moving data locally.

Comment: If possible I would move the source data to the computers hard drive as writing and reading across the network can dramatically slow things down. Also make sure the output raster is local, if possible.

Comment: Moving it is out of the question. I know doing it over the network decreases the speed by a lot.

Comment: @Dowlers loading from network is no longer *automatically* slower than disks, [Are networks now faster than disks? - Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/238417/are-networks-now-faster-than-disks) (though that's still true for most)

Answer (score 1):

Divide your orthophotos into a series of mosaic datasets (rather than a single mosaic dataset) and then clip each mosaic dataset individually. The different clips will output a series of raster datasets. You can put these into a mosaic dataset of their own or covert them to a single raster dataset using Mosaic to New Raster or Raster Catalog to Raster Dataset.

When I faced this problem before, I was trying to clip 6-inch resolution orthophotos covering about 175 km2 using a polygon feature class. I put the imagery in a single mosaic dataset and let the clip process run for about 6 days before ArcGIS crashed. I then divided the orthophotos into 10 different mosaic datasets and each clip only took an hour to process. I was able to clip all of the photos in one day.